# Redis's Redisson's API method .unlock() is not releasing the lock, trying from the same instance

Tags: java, redis

I have created singleton redisson instance in my Java application, which I am using to communicate to redis servers.
Now using this redisson instance, I am acquiring a lock which after getting some task done, I am releasing. But after calling unlock method, I still see redis have the lock and other threads are unable to acquire the lock.
Below is the code snippet, I am using:

```
class RedisInstance
{
   static RedisInstance ins;
   private RedisInstance()
     {
       ins = new RedisInstance();
     }
   public static RedisInstance getInstance()
     {
       return ins;
     }
   //Acquire the lock:   
   public boolean acquireLock(String lockKey)
     {
         RLock redisLock = getRedisClient().getLock(lockKey);
         boolean isLockFree;
         try 
         {
            isLockFree = redisLock.tryLock(lockAcquistionTimeLimit, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if(isLockFree)
            {
                 redisLock.lock();
                 logger.info("lock acquired for: {}", lockKey);
                 return true;
            }
         } 
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
             logger.error("Got exception {} in acquiring Redis Lock for: {}" , e, lockKey);
         }
         
         return false;
     }


   //Release the lock:
   public void unlock(String lockKey)
     {
         RLock redisLock = getRedisClient().getLock(lockKey);
         redisLock.unlock();
         logger.debug("IS redis locked "+redisLock.isLocked());
         logger.info("lock released for: {}", lockKey);
     }
}
```

```
class A
{
   RedisIns ins = RedisInstance.getInstance();
   public void run() 
        {
        if(ins.acquireLock(lockKey))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        //do some processing takes less than a second       
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ins.unlock(lockKey);
                    }
                }
         }
   //In my main method:
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     A a = new A();
     A b = new A();
     Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
     Thread t2 = new Thread(b);
     t1.start();
     Thread.sleep(5000); //just to mock, lets say t1 finishes before t2 starts
     t2.start();
   }
}
```

After t1 calls `ins.unlock(lockKey);`, the log `logger.debug("IS redis locked "+redisLock.isLocked());` says: true and `t2` is unable to acquire the lock.

But if I replace `redisLock.unlock();` with `redisLock.forceUnlock();` everything is working as expected.
Dont know why unlock() is unable to release the lock forceUnlock() is able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tryLock returns true if it acquired the lock. So calling lock after is unnecessary, and I think it may be the cause of your problem. The implementation probably expects an even number of lock/unlock and in you case you have one more lock than unlock.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing it out, I removed the additional lock() and it is working now, but for Redis why is it doing so, isn't it supposed to have only one lock and moreover this is a lock not a semaphore where it is keeping a track of number of lock() and unlock() called.

Comment: From the documentation it says that it implements a remote java concurrent lock. I think the lock counting is to allow reentrant locking, if lock/unlock is not balanced it would not allow a method that acquires a lock to call another method acquiring the same lock and unlocking it, because it would release the lock from the first method before the protected block is exited.